# Adding images to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to add two different images to a database but it just adds one and then adds the same one for the second value.

This is the controller which I add many photos to database

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,title,bodyofarticle")] article article )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         db.articles.Add(article);
         db.SaveChanges();
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;

            string saveFileName = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
            string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + hpf.FileName));
            Request.Files[file].SaveAs(location);
            image imag = new image();
            imag.url = Url.Content("~/images/" + saveFileName);
            imag.articleid = article.id;
            db.image.Add(imag);
            article.images.Add(imag);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }   
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    
  <input type="file" multiple=multiple id="file" name="files" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.Files return HttpFileCollection type an object.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection(v=vs.110).aspx
In order to get specific file in the files you can use object's properties by index Files[0],Files[1] or named Files[firstName],Files[secondName]
According to your code,you only work with just one file in the Files object.

Comment: excuse me sir but i'm using string file in order to get the names of the files in the request i tried your way by using the integer instead of string but an exception occuered  here's the exception :"An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WEBSITI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."
i'm really thankful that you're helping me and give me some of your time

Comment: Files[0] returns HttpPostedFile type object.Read details of this object from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,title,bodyofarticle")] article article /*, HttpPostedFileBase file*/)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 db.articles.Add(article);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                    string saveFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(location);
                    image imag = new image();
                    imag.url = Url.Content("~/images/" + saveFileName);
                    imag.articleid = article.id;
                    db.image.Add(imag);
                    article.images.Add(imag);

```
            }


                db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(article);
    }
```

//wish the rest get the benefits :)